# How do I change the html in the cover file when using ebooklib?

Tags: python, epub, ebooklib

The problem I was facing was that I didn't like the html file ebooklib was making for my cover. I was thinking of using svg tags, etc. With other Ebooklib items, setting content is how to change the html, as shown in tutorials.

In my code, I try

```
book = epub.EpubBook()
book.set_cover(cover_image, open(cover_image, 'rb').read())
cover_page = book.get_item_with_id('cover')
cover_page.content = some_html
```

But changing the content this way doesn't seem to do anything at all for the cover.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/aerkalov/ebooklib/blob/master/ebooklib/epub.py, ebooklib's EpubCoverHtml sets content in it's get_content method, but it doesn't seem to use it, and there doesn't seem to be a way to edit the content because it's always regenerated inside this method.

```
def get_content(self):
        """
        Returns content for cover page as HTML string. Content will be of type 'str' (Python 2) or 'bytes' (Python 3).
        :Returns:
          Returns content of this document.
        """

        self.content = self.book.get_template('cover')

        tree = parse_string(super(EpubCoverHtml, self).get_content())
        tree_root = tree.getroot()

        images = tree_root.xpath('//xhtml:img', namespaces={'xhtml': NAMESPACES['XHTML']})

        images[0].set('src', self.image_name)
        images[0].set('alt', self.title)

        tree_str = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)

        return tree_str
```

To actually modify what the cover html looks like, it seems like you have to modify the template:

```
cover_template = six.b('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
 <head>
  <style>
    body { margin: 0em; padding: 0em; }
    img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <img src="" alt="" />
 </body>
</html>''')
book.set_template(name='cover', value=cover_template)
```

Note: this is actually the default template.